# Tensorflow rnn_decoder usage : Expected size[1] in [0, 0] error message

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I have some problems about the usage of *embedding_rnn_decoder* in tensorflow 
[sample code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py).

Here is my code :

```
vocal_size = 407
embedding_size = 200

def decoder(input_,initial_state):
    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(decoder_state_num,num_proj=vocab_size)
    output,state=seq2seq.embedding_rnn_decoder(input_,initial_state,lstm,vocab_size,embedding_size,update_embedding_for_previous=True)
    return  output

decoder_input = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])]
predict_result=decoder(decoder_input,encoder_output)
```

and when  i run the code :

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(predict_result, feed_dict = {input: [input_one_hot[0]] , decoder_input[0]: label[0]})
```

`input_one_hot`: is a 6228 size list with 1*24 np.array elements in it. And I think problem isn't here. 
It is the input of a simple DNN and its output is used as the decoder's state. I've checked the shape and it didn't have any error.

`label[0]` : is a list of batch_size*1 np.array.

It will output an error :

```
tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Expected size[1] in [0, 0], but got 407
```

It seems like it automatically feeds the previous decoder output (shape (?,407)) into decoder's input of the next time step. But I didn't set the boolen `feed_previous` to True...

I've also tried different types of `label` to feed_dict in decoder_input, but it just can't work.

What should I modify to make the code work ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Clearly some shapes are mismatched, but it's hard to tell from your code snippets which ones. It would be easier to help if you posted the whole error message.